# How to call JavaScript object via variable?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I've got a series of JavaScript objects and a function to tie them together as a questionnaire.

If I call the function directly from the code like `setQuestion(Q1)`, it works fine;

```
function setQuestion(Q) {
     console.log(Q);          \\ Logs the Q1 object
     console.log(Q.answers);  \\ Logs the Q1.answers object
     console.log(Q2.answers); \\ Logs the Q2.answers object
}
```

But the variable `Q` is based upon a dynamically created attribute `followup` on a input field, for instance;

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" followup="Q2" value="A2" id="A2">
```

But when I use that attribute to call the `setQuestion` function, it doesn't recognize the object;

```
var followup = this.getAttribute('followup');
setQuestion(followup);
```

Say that `followup` is `Q2`;

```
function setQuestion(Q) {
     console.log(Q);          \\ Logs `Q2` as text
     console.log(Q.answers);  \\ Logs `undefined`
     console.log(Q2.answers); \\ Logs the Q2.answers object
}
```

It's clear that the function sees the attribute value as a textvalue, and thus doesn't get the object, so how can I make it see the attribute value variable as the related object?

FYI: the objects are defined like this;

```
var Q1 = { ... };
var Q2 = { ... };
etc.
```

Comment: Use an object indexed by Qs instead, eg `const allQs = { Q1: { answers: ... }, Q2: { ...` and then you can just use bracket notation to look up the proper object on `allQs`

Comment: @CertainPerformance; that works while maintaining the flexibility I need! If you'd like, post this as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You could move the questions into a questionaire and use the handed over values as key.

```
var Q1 = { ... },
    Q2 = { ... },
    questionaire = { Q1, Q2, ...};
```